# Starting karaf in mvn deployed servicemix 7

Tags: java, maven

On Fedora 39 rawhide, I have finally got mvn-3.9.1-3 to complete the "jar:jar install:install" goals. But using **find** I could not find executable files for karaf or a **bin** dir. **dnf** has no installable for *servicemix*.

The localhost;8181/system/console has 404.
How can I read status of sevicemix or start? I downloaded **servicemix** direct from apache.

Thanks for your support.